# Set Canvas as background

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am having trouble setting the canvas as a background element. At the moment the canvas is separated from the header tag as you will see in the example. 
*The canvas `#myCanvas`is also generated by javascript. I have tried using z-index but that has not worked. Here is the jsbin link.
http://jsbin.com/zikisu/1/

```
#myCanvas{
height: 400px;
width: 100%;
padding: 0px; z-index: -1; }
#mainTitle{
  z-index: 2;
}

h1 {

        color: #662d86;
}

#triangles{
    height: 400px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: -moz-element(#myCanvas);
}

#output{
    height: 400px;
}
<body>
  <div class="container" id="triangles">
                <div id="output">
                    <div id="mainTitle" class="row">
                        <div class="col-med-12 text-center">
                            <h1>Innovation
                            </h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>  
</body>
```

Comment: Please paste your code here, if that pastebin dies and others have a similar issue, they'll be lost without your code.

Comment: Your example code doesn't actually have a `<canvas>` in it ...

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to "set canvas as background", because in HTML/CSS only colors and images can be backgrounds.

If you want the *effect* of the canvas element appearing as if it were the background, simply:

1. put the `<canvas>` at the DOM root (ie. make it a child of `<body>`)
2. put any other elements adjacent to it (ie. also as children of `<body>`)
3. use CSS to position the other elements on top of the canvas element

It might be easier to do #2 and #3 by putting all the other elements in to a single `<div>` container.  In other words:

```
<body>
    <canvas></canvas>
    <div id="container">
        <!-- put the rest of your page here -->
    </div>
</body>
```

That way you only have to style `<div id="container">`.

Comment: _“There is no way to "set canvas as background"”_ – not directly, but a data URI can be created from the canvas content, and that can be used as `url` value for `background-image`.

Comment: Interesting idea.  I think (based on their pastebin) @Grzes Slania was trying to make an animated canvas the background, so they'd have to use that technique constantly to keep updating the background image.  That *might* work, but I'd be concerned about the performance complications ... and also it seems unnecessary since you don't need the canvas to be a *literal* background in order for it to have the *effect* of being a background.

Comment: Yes, for an animated background you are right, using the element directly would be preferable. _“you don't need the canvas to be a literal background in order for it to have the effect of being a background”_ – not if you want it to be used only once – but if f.e. tiling was a requirement (as would be achieved using `background-repeat`), setting it as an actual background image might be preferable (as opposed to having to use multiple canvas elements, position them correctly and keeping them in sync.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of code to go through, but as a start: Try adjusting the CSS so that the canvas is treated as a *fixed* element (the browser may also give it a separate bitmap so performance is a tad better as well):

```
#myCanvas{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1; 
}
```